# Could not add the table (

Tags: sql, inner-join, ms-query, sage-erp

The following code works in Sage200.

```
SELECT bcs.BomReference
    ,bcs.DateTimeCosted
    ,bcs.TotalCost
FROM (
    SELECT BomReference
        ,Max(DateTimeCosted) AS MaxDate
    FROM NDM_Sage200.dbo.BomCostSession BomCostSession
    GROUP BY BomReference
    ) AS ldc
INNER JOIN BomCostSession AS bcs ON bcs.BomReference = ldc.BomReference
    AND bcs.DateTimeCosted = ldc.MaxDate
ORDER BY BomReference
```

As soon as I try extending this with an INNER JOIN to another table to get more columns (using *BomReference*), I get the error message:
*Could not add the table (*.
See below for example of modified code;  I have to use 2 joins to get to the table I need, but have the same error whatever I join onto the working code.

```
SELECT bcs.BomReference, bcs.DateTimeCosted, bcs.TotalCost, BomBuildProduct.StockDescription 
FROM (
SELECT BomReference, 
Max(DateTimeCosted) AS MaxDate
FROM NDM_Sage200.dbo.BomCostSession BomCostSession 
GROUP BY BomReference 
) AS ldc 
INNER JOIN 
BomCostSession as bcs 
ON bcs.BomReference = ldc.BomReference AND 
bcs.DateTimeCosted = ldc.MaxDate
***** Fails when adding INNER JOIN here *****
    INNER JOIN
    BomBuildPackage
    ON BomCostSession.BomBuildPackageID = BomBuildPackage.BomBuildPackageID
    INNER JOIN
    BomBuildProduct
    ON BomBuildPackage.BomRecordID = BomBuildProduct.BomRecordID
    ORDER BY BomReference
```

What am I doing wrong ?   I need to expand the query with data from several tables.
I also think that when using MSQuery on the section that works, it offers no options to add any tables - this makes it rather difficult to try options.
Why ?

Comment: Please edit your question with the query that is failing.  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: For your table that is working you have full path 'NDM_Sage200.dbo.BomCostSession', but for the join tables you have only the name. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The issue with MSQuery is that it attempts to display your query graphically in it's design view, this works OK for simple queries but not for complex queries which usually generates the could not add table message. The way I found around this is to treat your query as one big sub query inside a wrapper query, this forces MSQuery to give up the design view and work as pure SQL text.

Another issue might be that for one table you have the full path but not the others, is it correct for the table you have included it and does it need to be used on the other tables.

Here is an example of the changes I think you should make:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT bcs.BomReference
  ,bcs.DateTimeCosted
  ,bcs.TotalCost
  ,BomBuildProduct.StockDescription
FROM 
  (SELECT BomReference
     ,Max(DateTimeCosted) AS MaxDate
   FROM NDM_Sage200.dbo.BomCostSession BomCostSession
   GROUP BY BomReference) AS ldc
INNER JOIN NDM_Sage200.dbo.BomCostSession AS bcs ON bcs.BomReference = ldc.BomReference
  AND bcs.DateTimeCosted = ldc.MaxDate
INNER JOIN NDM_Sage200.dbo.BomBuildPackage ON BomCostSession.BomBuildPackageID = BomBuildPackage.BomBuildPackageID
INNER JOIN NDM_Sage200.dbo.BomBuildProduct ON BomBuildPackage.BomRecordID = BomBuildProduct.BomRecordID) x
ORDER BY BomReference
```